# How could I use Cordova with Meteor & React?

Tags: javascript, cordova, reactjs, meteor

I'm with a difficult to use a Cordova plugin with Meteor and React, from the docs I saw that:

> You should wrap any functionality which relies on a Cordova plugin in
>   a Meteor.startup() block to make sure the plugin has been fully
>   initialized (by listening to the deviceready event). For example, when
>   using the Cordova geolocation plugin:

```js
Meteor.startup(function() {
    // Here we can be sure the plugin has been initialized
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success); });
}
```

And I know I need to define this:

```js
Cordova.depends({
    'org.apache.cordova.camera': '0.3.1'
});
```

But I have some questions:

1º - Can I put this function `Meteor.startup()` anywhere inside server and about inside the client?

2º - Where I need to put the `Cordova.depends()`? There is a packages file on Meteor > local, but it's not a js file.

3º - After define the `Cordova.depends()` could I invoke the functions from the client side with react? If so, How?

Some example with that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After sometime of research I found the answers:

1 - I already had the `Meteor.startup()`, it was inside the file main.js inside the client folder.

2 - I don't need to put the `Cordova.depends()`, according to the [docs](https://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html):

> In contrast to Meteor packages, you’ll have to specify the exact
>   version of the plugin. This can be a bit of a pain because you first
>   need to look up what the most recent (compatible) version of a plugin
>   is before you can add it.

3 - I can invoke the functions of Cordova plugins on the client or on the server, but I need to make that just with a native app, I'm making a webapp now, then I can't do that. But there is a way to do that with Meteor, following the [Developing on device](https://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html#running-your-app) session.